# Bokeh embedded with custom .css and .js

Tags: python, html, css, tornado, bokeh

I'm trying to hack up the [tornado embedded app example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/tornado_embed.py) to add custom css and js. I can't seem to get the css and js linked appropriately. Should I expect the css and js files to link normally in the document head?

```
<head>
<link href="/static/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/static/js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
```

...or should I be using the [bokeh custom static handler](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/server/views/static_handler.py) to load everything first?

...or or can I just pass it into the indexhandler kind of like so:

```
class IndexHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = env.get_template('embed.html')
        static = env.get_static('/css/style.css')
        script = server_document('default')
        self.write(template.render(script=script, template="Tornado", static=static))
```

For Reference:

```
app
|__data
|__static
|    |__css
|       |__custom.css
|    |__js
|       |__custom.js
|__templates
|    |__embed.html
|__main.py
```

Just looking for some general guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add something like this to `extra_patterns` when calling `Server`:

```
(server_static_route, StaticFileHandler, { "path" : local_path_to_static_dir })
```

where `StaticFileHandler` comes from `tornado.web`.

Answer (score 1):

bigreddot's answer is correct, but I'd like to add some detail. In my case I want to access the contents of `/static/css`. You'll need these includes:

```
from tornado.web import StaticFileHandler
import os.path as op
```

and then add the following Application handler when opening the server:

```
[(r'/static/css/(.*)', StaticFileHandler,
 {'path': op.normpath(op.dirname(op.abspath(__file__)) + r'/static/css')})]
```

This gets passed along with any other Application handlers to the `extra_patterns` parameter.